# Python shared lock between Threads and EventLoops

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, python-asyncio

Consider the situation where I have a main thread with one (or more async eventloops) and multiple python threads, running at the same time.

I want to have a lock, which works both inside threads and inside eventloops.
For example when the lock is acquired in an async EventLoop, other async loops and threads wait for the exact same lock.

How should I implement this?

I know about `threading.Lock` and `asyncio.Lock`. But I am not sure if I can use `threading.Lock` inside an async task or vice versa.

Comment: Why are you using both threads and async? Usually it is not recommended to use both features at the same time.

Comment: I know it does not sound good but an old library is working with threads and another project source code is  working async. I'd rather not to re implement the library with async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea that came to my mind was to create a new class of Lock or Queue, which has two objects for each type of processing.

But some people have already implemented this idea and more. for example:

- [janus](https://github.com/aio-libs/janus)
- [aioprocessing](https://github.com/dano/aioprocessing)